# How to get branch into manifest

Tags: git, maven, buildnumber-maven-plugin

Using the `buildnumber` maven plugin, I would like to get the branch stored in my jar manifest. I have tried it two different ways, shown below.

Here is the output from my build (relevant section only)

`[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) @ myproject ---
[INFO] ShortRevision tag detected. The value is '7'.
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/workspace/myproject' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--verify' '--short=7' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /workspace/myproject
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: ed5ea17 at timestamp: 1479511476753
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: bug/abuginthesystem`

Here the plugin section from attempt 1 (SCMBranch key from plugin website):

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        <shortRevisionLength>7</shortRevisionLength>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Build-OS>${os.name} ${os.version}</Build-OS>
                <Build-Java>Java ${java.version}</Build-Java>
                <Build-Number>${buildNumber}</Build-Number>
                <Build-Branch>${SCMBranch}</Build-Branch>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`

Attempt 2 using the build out:

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        <shortRevisionLength>7</shortRevisionLength>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Build-OS>${os.name} ${os.version}</Build-OS>
                <Build-Java>Java ${java.version}</Build-Java>
                <Build-Number>${buildNumber}</Build-Number>
                <Build-Branch>${buildScmBranch}</Build-Branch>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`

Manifest output from both is:

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Java: Java 1.7.0_79
Build-Number: ed5ea17
Build-OS: Linux 4.4.0-47-generic
Built-By: mondain
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_79
Build-Branch: 
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver`

Comment: So yet more the good and bad side of SO, someone -1's and another person provides a solid answer +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the following in your `manifestEntries`:

```
<Build-Branch>${buildScmBranch}</Build-Branch>
```

Then you should use the following in the configuration for the `buildnumber-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
    <configuration>
        <scmBranchPropertyName>buildScmBranch</scmBranchPropertyName>
      ...
```

Comment: Outstanding! thank you for that config, works exactly like I wanted.